# Changing the position of the plot labels in ListLinePlot

Tags: plotting, labeling

[image]

How can I change the position of the labels in `ListLinePlot` to be on the left-hand side of the curves instead of the right-hand side? In addition, how can I make the labels to appear just for two of the curves, not all of them?

In the following, I am plotting the solutions of `NSolve`, while labeling each curve with the value of a parameter (a) which is specific for that curve.

```
gamma4 = .4;
gamma3 = .284;
gamma2 = .265;
gamma1 = .484;
z3 = 10000;
z2 = 32000;
z1 = 75000;
zbar4 = 4800;
zbar3 = 20050;
zbar2 = 46200;
zbar1 = 138100;
h4 = .301;
h3 = .404;
h2 = .25;
h1 = .045;
p1 = 3.89;
p2 = 4.92;
p3 = 5.22;
p4 = 5.39;
g1 = 0;
g2 = 0.44;
g3 = 0.88;
g4 = 1.76;




eq1 = (\[Tau]1/(1 - \[Tau]1)) - ((1 - 
       g1 - (g2 a p2 + g3 a p3 + g4 a p4)) (zbar1 - 
        z1)/((1 - ((g1 a p1/\[Tau]1) + g2 a p2 + g3 a p3 + 
            g4 a p4)) zbar1 gamma1));
Print["0=", eq1];

eq2 = (\[Tau]2/(1 - \[Tau]2)) - (((1 - 
          g2 - (g1 a p1 + g3 a p3 + g4 a p4)) h2 (zbar2 - z2) + (1 - 
          g1 - (g2 a p2 + g3 a p3 + g4 a p4)) h1 (z1 - 
          z2))/((1 - (g1 a p1 + (g2 a p2/\[Tau]2) + g3 a p3 + 
           g4 a p4)) (zbar2 h2 gamma2)));
Print["0=", eq2];

eq3 = (\[Tau]3/(1 - \[Tau]3)) - (((1 - 
          g3 - (g1 a p1 + g2 a p2 + g4 a p4)) h3 (zbar3 - 
          z3) + ((1 - g2 - (g1 a p1 + g3 a p3 + g4 a p4)) h2 + (1 - 
             g1 - (g2 a p2 + g3 a p3 + g4 a p4)) h1) (z2 - 
          z3))/((1 - (g1 a p1 + g2 a p2 + (g3 a p3/\[Tau]3) + 
           g4 a p4)) zbar3 h3 gamma3));
Print["0=", eq3];

eq4 = (\[Tau]4/(1 - \[Tau]4)) - (((1 - 
          g4 - (g1 a p1 + g2 a p2 + 
            g3 a p3)) h4 (zbar4) + ((1 - 
             g3 - (g1 a p1 + g2 a p2 + g4 a p4)) h3 + (1 - 
             g2 - (g1 a p1 + g3 a p3 + g4 a p4)) h2 + (1 - 
             g1 - (g2 a p2 + g3 a p3 + 
               g4 a p4)) h1) z3)/((1 - (g1 a p1 + g2 a p2 + 
           g3 a p3 + (g4 a p4/\[Tau]4))) zbar4*h4*gamma4));
Print["0=", eq4];

set = a -> # & /@ Range[0, 3, 0.1];

f[x_] := Module[{v}, 
  v = Table[{\[Tau]4, \[Tau]3, \[Tau]2, \[Tau]1} /. 
     NSolve[{eq1 == 0, eq2 == 0, eq3 == 0, 
        eq4 == 0 && \[Tau]1 > 0 && \[Tau]2 > 0 && \[Tau]3 > 
          0 && \[Tau]4 > 0} /. 
       x[[i]], {\[Tau]1, \[Tau]2, \[Tau]3, \[Tau]4}], {i, 1, 
     Length[x], 1}]; v = Flatten[v, 1];


  mR = Labeled[
    ListLinePlot[v, 
     PlotLabels -> 
      Placed[Flatten[{x[[1]], ConstantArray["", Length[x] - 3], 
         x[[-2]], ""}], Left], GridLines -> {None, {1}}, 
     GridLinesStyle -> 
      Directive[
       AbsoluteThickness[3/2] ColorData[97, 
          2] Method -> {"GridLinesInFront" -> True}], 
     PlotLabel -> Style["MTR- Rawlsian", FontSize -> 18], 
     PlotRange -> {0, 1.05}, PlotLegends -> Values@x, 
     PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 10}, 
     Ticks -> {{{1, zbar4}, {2, zbar3}, {3, zbar2}, {4, zbar1}}, {0.2,
         0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 0.9, 1}}, 
     TicksStyle -> {Directive[Red, 12], Directive[Red, 8]}, 
     ImageSize -> {800, 300}], "Income Brackets"]]

f[set]
```

Comment: Why doesn't `v = Table[{\[Tau]4, \[Tau]3, \[Tau]2, \[Tau]1} /. aR];` have a second argument? (slightly unrelated to your main question)

Comment: A starting point could be `PlotLabels -> Callout[Values@x, Before]`, but I didn't manage to get MMA to spread them nicely so that they don't overlap.

Comment: As for omitting some of them: Simply put `None` in the list of labels, i.e. `PlotLabels -> {Label1, Label2, None, Label4, None, ...}`

Comment: Spent some time on this, it seems to be very difficult to move the labels properly to the left. `Placed[..., Left]` should work, but it always looks terrible.

Comment: I have corrected the second argument of Table. But can't get the correct labels yet! PlotLabels seems to be not available for ListLinePlot in Version 10!

Comment: @Hossein wait a second, you say you are using mathematica 10, then how could you plot  plotlabels in the first image?

Answer (score 1):

time for a little trick: since you don't have PlotLabels i suggest you to use Inset to  achieve a similar result

use Epilog-> Inset to insert the text you want in the position {x,y}.

```
gamma4 = .4;
gamma3 = .284;
gamma2 = .265;
gamma1 = .484;
z3 = 10000;
z2 = 32000;
z1 = 75000;
zbar4 = 4800;
zbar3 = 20050;
zbar2 = 46200;
zbar1 = 138100;
h4 = .301;
h3 = .404;
h2 = .25;
h1 = .045;
p1 = 3.89;
p2 = 4.92;
p3 = 5.22;
p4 = 5.39;
g1 = 0;
g2 = 0.44;
g3 = 0.88;
g4 = 1.76;




eq1 = (\[Tau]1/(1 - \[Tau]1)) - ((1 - 
       g1 - (g2 a p2 + g3 a p3 + g4 a p4)) (zbar1 - 
        z1)/((1 - ((g1 a p1/\[Tau]1) + g2 a p2 + g3 a p3 + 
            g4 a p4)) zbar1 gamma1));
Print["0=", eq1];

eq2 = (\[Tau]2/(1 - \[Tau]2)) - (((1 - 
          g2 - (g1 a p1 + g3 a p3 + g4 a p4)) h2 (zbar2 - z2) + (1 - 
          g1 - (g2 a p2 + g3 a p3 + g4 a p4)) h1 (z1 - 
          z2))/((1 - (g1 a p1 + (g2 a p2/\[Tau]2) + g3 a p3 + 
           g4 a p4)) (zbar2 h2 gamma2)));
Print["0=", eq2];

eq3 = (\[Tau]3/(1 - \[Tau]3)) - (((1 - 
          g3 - (g1 a p1 + g2 a p2 + g4 a p4)) h3 (zbar3 - 
          z3) + ((1 - g2 - (g1 a p1 + g3 a p3 + g4 a p4)) h2 + (1 - 
             g1 - (g2 a p2 + g3 a p3 + g4 a p4)) h1) (z2 - 

          z3))/((1 - (g1 a p1 + g2 a p2 + (g3 a p3/\[Tau]3) + 
           g4 a p4)) zbar3 h3 gamma3));
Print["0=", eq3];

eq4 = (\[Tau]4/(1 - \[Tau]4)) - (((1 - 
          g4 - (g1 a p1 + g2 a p2 + 
            g3 a p3)) h4 (zbar4) + ((1 - 
             g3 - (g1 a p1 + g2 a p2 + g4 a p4)) h3 + (1 - 
             g2 - (g1 a p1 + g3 a p3 + g4 a p4)) h2 + (1 - 
             g1 - (g2 a p2 + g3 a p3 + 
               g4 a p4)) h1) z3)/((1 - (g1 a p1 + g2 a p2 + 
           g3 a p3 + (g4 a p4/\[Tau]4))) zbar4*h4*gamma4));
Print["0=", eq4];

set = a -> # & /@ Range[0, 3, 0.1];

f[x_] := Module[{v}, 
  v = Table[{\[Tau]4, \[Tau]3, \[Tau]2, \[Tau]1} /. 
     NSolve[{eq1 == 0, eq2 == 0, eq3 == 0, 
        eq4 == 0 && \[Tau]1 > 0 && \[Tau]2 > 0 && \[Tau]3 > 
          0 && \[Tau]4 > 0} /. 
       x[[i]], {\[Tau]1, \[Tau]2, \[Tau]3, \[Tau]4}], {i, 1, 
     Length[x], 1}]; v = Flatten[v, 1];
  mR = Labeled[
    ListLinePlot[v, GridLines -> {None, {1}}, 
     GridLinesStyle -> 
      Directive[
       AbsoluteThickness[3/2] ColorData[97, 
          2] Method -> {"GridLinesInFront" -> True}], 
     PlotLabel -> Style["MTR- Rawlsian", FontSize -> 18], 
     PlotRange -> {0, 1.05}, PlotLegends -> Values@x, 
     PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 10}, 
     Ticks -> {{{1, zbar4}, {2, zbar3}, {3, zbar2}, {4, zbar1}}, {0.2,
         0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 0.9, 1}}, 
     TicksStyle -> {Directive[Red, 12], Directive[Red, 8]}, 
     ImageSize -> {800, 300}, 
     Epilog -> 
      Inset[Style[StringJoin["a = " , ToString[Values[x][[1]]]], Red], {1, 
        0.73}]], "Income Brackets"]

  ]


f[set]
```

Update: the number in the image is wrong but the code is now fixed

[image]